# Default Clasure Where in Includes Generyc Repository Entity Framework 6.1 Code First c#

Tags: generics, c#-4.0, lambda, ef-code-first, repository-pattern

I have a generic repository where all the database tables have a column to delete logical. For example:

[View my simple database diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PFwd.png)

I need all the queries held by the repository from the Sale table is added to condition negating delete columns, including when the tables (SaleItem, Item, Customer) were included.

```
[Table("Sale")]
public partial class Sale
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Sale()
    {        
        SaleItems = new HashSet<SaleItem>();            
    }

    public long ID { get; set; }
    public long? CostumerID { get; set; }
    public virtual Costumer Costumer { get; set; }
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<SaleItem> SaleItems { get; set; }

public class SaleRepository : BaseRepository<Sale>
{
    public async Task<Sale> FindOneAndRelatedAsync(object id)
    {
        return await FindAsync(id,
            (s => s.Costumer),
            (s => s.SaleItems),
            (s => s.SaleItems.Select(si => si.Item))
        );
 }

public class BaseRepository<T> : IBaseRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private string deletedName = "Deleted";
    public async virtual Task<T> FindAsync(object id, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes)
    {
        return await FindAsync(id, false, includes);
    }

    public async virtual Task<T> FindAsync(object id, bool hasDeleted = false, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes)
    {
        var query = DbSet.AsQueryable();

        query = includeRelationships(includes, query);

        query = query.Where(idPredicateExpression(id));

        if (!hasDeleted)
            query = query.Where(deletedPredicateExpression());

        return await query.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }

    protected Expression<Func<T, bool>> deletedPredicateExpression()
    {
        return columnPredicateExpression(deletedName, false);
    }

    protected Expression<Func<T, bool>> columnPredicateExpression(string columnName, object keyword)
    {
        var arg = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "p");

        var method = keyword.GetType() == typeof(string) ? typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) }) : keyword.GetType().GetMethod("Equals", new[] { keyword.GetType() });

        var body = Expression.Call(
            Expression.Property(arg, columnName),
            method,
            Expression.Constant(keyword));

        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, arg);
    }

    protected IQueryable<T> includeRelationships(Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes, IQueryable<T> query)
    {
        if (includes != null)
        {
            query = includes.Aggregate(query, (current, include) => current.Include(include));
        }

        return query;
    }
```

As can be seen in the above code, I can create an Expression to add the condition *WHERE* somene the Sale entity with the method *deletedPredicateExpression()*. It works perfectly. But the entities that are included by *includeRelationships()* method (SaleItem, Item and Costumer) must include the condition *WHERE*.

When the relationship is 1:n, as the *Costumer* entity. I can perform insert the code below.

```
    protected IQueryable<T> includeRelationships(Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes, IQueryable<T> query)
    {
        if (includes != null)
        {
            int i = 0;
            query = includes.Aggregate(query, (current, include) => current.Include(include));
            foreach (var include in includes)
            {
                    var test = test(include.Body.Type);
                    query = query.Where(test).AsQueryable();
            }

        }

        return query;
    }

    protected Expression<Func<T, bool>> test(Type typeEntity)
    {
        string columnName = typeEntity.Name +"." + deletedName;

            string[] props = columnName.Split('.');
            Type type = typeof(T);
            ParameterExpression arg = Expression.Parameter(type, "m");
            Expression expr = arg;
            foreach (string prop in props)
            {
                // use reflection (not ComponentModel) to mirror LINQ
                PropertyInfo pi = type.GetProperty(prop);
                expr = Expression.Property(expr, pi);
                type = pi.PropertyType;
            }
            var val1 = Expression.Constant(false);
            Expression e1 = Expression.Equal(expr, val1);
            Type delegateType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(T), type);
            return (Expression<Func<T, bool>>)Expression.Lambda(delegateType, e1, arg);  
    }
```

If my relationship is N:N or when I need to access an object inside a collection as in entity *Item* that is below *SaleItems* can not include the clause *WHERE* because it does not have the property *Deleted* of the object *SaleItems* or *Item* for example.

**Exist a way to filter all the entities to always generate a query considering a condition in the case *WHERE Deleted  == 0* by default?**

Answer (score 0):

Create a base entity that include Delete status property. Then, inherit all your class from this base entity. So, you can filter anywhere with `Where`.

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    public BaseEntity()
    {
        IsDelete = false;
    }
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

   public bool IsDelete { get; set; }
}

public class Yourclass : BaseEntity // Sale class or somethingelse
{
  //
}
```

And you need to use this `BaseEntity` class as main class instead of `class` for generic T class.

```
public class BaseRepository<T> : IBaseRepository<T> where T : BaseEntity
{
   public T GetById(int id)
    {
        return this.Entities.Single(item => item.Id == id && !item.IsDelete);            

    }
    // implement your methods here by using IsDelete property in `Where`          condition.
}
```

Using this `BaseEntity` as main entity class, you can filter all classes by delete status even in collection.